# Container for links

Tags: css, html

I am trying to do something similar as 
   [image]
where there is one container for the **top Info** and the second container for **links like NEWS** and such

> My problem is that : the links refuse to stay in horizontal

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#tabLinks{
list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 18px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 /*width: 890px;*/


}


#tabLinks li ul {
list-style-type: none;
  /*margin: 010px 0 ;*/
   display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}



#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
   padding:5px;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="header">
<h1>City Gallery</h1>
</div>

<div id="tabLinks"> 
   <ul>
     <div = class="a">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a</li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <li><a href=Blog.html>Blog</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <li><a href=Terms.html>Terms</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <li><a href=Privacy.html>Privacy</a></li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What problem are you specifically having trouble with?  The colors? The links being vertically-stacked instead of horizontally-listed?

Comment: the links refuse they stay in the container **inline**

Comment: You mean they're vertical instead of horizontal?

Comment: Is it because the rule `#tabLinks li ul` should be `#tabLinks ul li`?

Comment: Just remove the ul. Try `#tabLinks li { /* stuff */ }`

Comment: yeah the link refuse to stay vertical

Comment: @xdhmoore its not working lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use inline-block on the ul and li...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#header {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#tabLinks{
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 18px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
 /*width: 890px;*/
}

#tabLinks ul{
  display: inline-block;
}

#tabLinks li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
   padding:5px;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="header">
<h1>City Gallery</h1>
</div>

<div id="tabLinks"> 
   <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a</li>
      <li><a href=Blog.html>Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href=Terms.html>Terms</a></li>
      <li><a href=Privacy.html>Privacy</a></li>
     </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks good to me... I think `display:inline` on the `#tabLinks li` block would also work, but maybe `display:inline-block` gives you more control over things like padding...

Comment: what if i want to create this container just as the twitter one

Comment: the way twitter displayed the link , I am trying to replicate the same thing but with only 4 links under the main container @xdhmoore

Comment: Well it looks like what you have is a good start. Could you be more specific on what you are having trouble with?